# MongoDB Query Join Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

User will enter a input name and broadband Speed like below
**Name:** shankar
**Speed:**10Mbps
Then i need to display
 **Name:**Shankar 
 **Speed :** 10Mbps
**Data Used :** 500MB

from below given sample mongodb document structure  how to query in mongoDB?
**Parent Record is :**
{
subscriber_id : 001
name: shankar
total_data_used: 1000MB
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:03:00
}
{
subscriber_id : 002
name: John
total_data_used: 2000MB
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:10:00
}

**Detail or child record as follows:**

{
subscriber_id: 001
service:10Mbps
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:01:00
total_data_usage: 500MB
}

{
subscriber_id: 001
service:10Mbps
total_data_usage: 500MB
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:02:00
}

{
subscriber_id: 002
service:10Mbps
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:07:00
total_data_usage: 1000MB
}

{
subscriber_id: 002
service:10Mbps
total_data_usage: 1000MB
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:08:00
}

Anyone tell me in mongodb query how to retrieve

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: Not so sure about your question, if you wanna query the parent documents and children documents , and then join them in one document , mongodb don't support that. Maybe $aggregate can help but it's not how mongodb work. You have to make it in two query, one for parent, one for child

Comment: Looks like it may fit your requirement , but I am not sure about the performance . You'd better use an explain() to check the performance before you decide to use it.

Comment: ok  ill try  thanks john

Answer (score 1):

This query should work. The first 'lookup' stage joins the child collection with the parent collection based on the subscriber_id field. It appends all documents in parent collection which match in the subscriber_details array of the child document.

In your case, this will be the output after the first stage.

{
subscriber_id: 001,
service:10Mbps,
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:01:00,
total_data_usage: 500MB,
subscriber_details:[{
subscriber_id : 001,
name: shankar,
total_data_used: 1000MB,
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:03:00
}]
}

{
subscriber_id: 001,
service:10Mbps,
total_data_usage: 500MB,
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:02:00,
subscriber_details:[{
subscriber_id : 001,
name: shankar,
total_data_used: 1000MB,
Timestamp: 2016-Aug-01 00:03:00,
}]
}

After this stage, I am using a 'match' to filter out against your input conditions and then a 'project' stage to obtain the output in the form you desire.

```
db.child.aggregate([
{
   $lookup:
     {
       "from": "parent",
       "localField": "subscriber_id",
       "foreignField": "subscriber_id",
       "as": "subscriber_details"
     }
}, 
{
   $match:
     {
       "service":"<input_speed>",
       "subscriber_details.name":"<input_name>"
     }
},
{
   $project:
     {
       "_id":0
       "Name":"$subscriber_details.0.name"
       "Speed":"$service"
       "Data Used":"$total_data_usage"
     }
}])
```